# How do you export data from R as read-only?

Tags: r

I have to export .txt files which should be set as read-only in order to prevent unintentional editing of my output.

Is there a way to automatically export data from R in a format that cannot be edited once it's created? It may not necessarily have to be a .txt file, but that is what I am currently using at the moment.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Couldn't you use a system call (like ``chmod``) to set rights correctly?